# How to upload a Salesforce File using REST API properly?

Tags: api, rest, files, contentversion, fileupload

`GET /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0000v00000MFIVgAAP/VersionData` from this request I will get binary file content, but how can I use this content to recreate the file properly (using request to `POST /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentVersion`)?

I uploaded **.docx** through the UI and fetch its content. 
Then I uploded that content using the request:

**Endpoint**

> /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentVersion

**Headers**

> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary_string

**Body**

```
--boundary_string 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content"; 
Content-type: application/json

{"PathOnClient":"MyFile.docx"}

--boundary_string 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="MyFile.docx"

Binary data from the request to GET /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0000v00000MFIVgAAP/VersionData.

--boundary_string--
```

The request above is executed with a success status code, and the file was created successfully, but when I downloaded this file from UI, it became damaged :(
There may be something in the request body that I missed (but I don’t know what exactly is wrong), so the file creates damaged.
Can someone please provide me with a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue here, I've gotten this far but the file can't be opened, even though it's non-empty and it has binary data in it. Did you find a solution to this? Comparing my download to the original file, the file downloaded from salesforce is almost twice as big

Comment: yeah, It was the problem in a body. Using my own application and transferring data in proper format (binary format) everything works fine.

Comment: And you're sending binary data, not base64 encoded data? I'm trying to post the data to /ContentVersion, where the body is the binary data of a PNG file. The binary data looks fine, but when I upload to salesforce and download, the file is corrupt and slightly smaller than the original, which makes me wonder if salesforce is expecting base64 data here

Comment: it is exactly binary data

Comment: This maybe a silly question but how do you get the binary data from the actual document on your machine?

Comment: Precisely!  How do I put binary data into a text multipart document with text boundaries?

I notice when I try base64 I get precisely base64 back instead of my PDF.

Comment: Did anybody get to solve this? I'm having the same problem but with an audio file (m4a), the file get uploaded but the file is corrupted and can't be played...

Comment: This can happen with the multipart data encoding process isn't done quite correctly. If you use Postman, it can automatically do the multipart encoding for you.